# Event after OnItemsChanged and item containers generation

Tags: wpf

Is there an event (or protected method) occurring  after `OnItemsChanged`, and after item containers are generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I will answer myself. I don't know yet if this is good solution but I used something like this:

```
protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // ... stuff ...

    ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
}

private void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
        // ... do work here ...

        ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
    }
}
```

It seems to work...

Comment: Sorry to be repetitive... WHAT do you want that for??

Comment: Why does it matter? I wanted to do some work after `Items` are changed and containers for them are generated (specifically I want to measure required space for generated containers)...

Comment: sorry to bother you with such a queston. It's just that when people ask these kind of things it's usually because they're trying to do winforms stuff in WPF.